# creating or updating a specific record based on foreign key

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, foreign-keys, eloquent

I have two simple table and models : `photos` and `venues`.
there is a polymorphic relationship between these two classes.
A venue has a special kind of photo which is a header photo, and there should be **at most** one of those photos for each venue.(a venue can have none of it)
now How I can point that specif photo  from venues?
my photos table:

```
Schema::create('photos', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('path');
        $table->string('filename');
        $table->string('mime');
        $table->string('original_filename');   
        $table->integer('imageable_id');
        $table->string('imageable_type');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

I see two options, whether a foreign key on venues table pointing to a photos record or adding an attribute called is_header_photo to photos table.
for me, the first option seems right but I'm a bit confused how I'm supposed to change image_id on venues table to point to the right id. 
How can I update this field? and if you have a better solution I would be glad to be shared.

Comment: any help or just a hint?